# problem about split a string

Tags: python, string

I wrote a program to read a registry entry from a file.
And the entry looks like this:

```
reg='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TT\Tools\SYS\exePath' #it means rootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey='SOFTWARE\TT\Tools\SYS', property=exePath
```

I want to read this entry from the file and break it into rootKey, subKey and property.
Apparently, I can do it this way:

```
rootKey = reg.split('\\', 1)[0]
subKey = reg.split('\\', 1)[1].rsplit('\\', 1)[0]  #might be a stupid way
property = reg.rsplit('\\, 1)[1]
```

Maybe the entry is a stupid one, but any better way to break it into parts like above?

Comment: Use raw strings --- `reg.split(r'\')`

Comment: Looks like there is a similar question answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833441/is-there-a-pure-python-library-for-parsing-a-windows-registry-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

t=re.search(r"(.+?)\\(.+)\\(.+)", reg)
t.groups()
('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SOFTWARE\\TT\\Tools\\SYS', 'exePath')
```

Answer (score 2):

How about doing the following?  There's no need to call `.split()` so many times, anyway...

```
s = reg.split('\\')
property = s.pop()
root_key = s.pop(0)
sub_key = '\\'.join(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `partition` over `split` when I can, because `partition` ensures each of the returned tuple elements is a string.

```
root_key, _, s       = reg.partition("\\")
_, sub_key, property = s.rpartition("\\") # note, _r_partition
```